# Is it possible to show that $H_1^s(X;G) \cong H_1^s(X,a;G)$ via exact sequence of pair?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $a\in X$. Then since we have a short exact sequence
$$
   0 \to C_k^s(a;G) \to C_k^s(X;G) \to C_k^s(X,a;G) \to 0, \; k \geqslant 0
$$
of singlular chain complexes, where $C_k^s(X,a;G) = C_k^s(X;G) / C_k^s(a,G)$, then we can obtain the long exact sequence
$$
   \cdots \to H_{k+1}^s(X,a;G) \to H_k^s(a;G) \to H_k^s(X;G) \to H_k^s(X,a;G)\to \cdots \tag{1}
$$
of singular homology groups. But for $k\geqslant 1$ we have $H_k^s(a;G) = 0$. Then we have an exact sequence
$$
   0 \to H_{k+1}^s(X;G) \xrightarrow{i}  H_{k+1}^s(X,a;G) \xrightarrow{j} 0 \to H_k^s(X;G), \; k \geqslant 1.
$$
Then $\ker i = \mathop {\mathrm{im}} \, 0 = 0$, so $i$ is injective. And $\mathop{\mathrm{im}} \,i = \ker j = H_{k+1}^s(X,a;G)$, so $i$ is surjective. Hence $i$ is a bijection and we have
$$
  H_k^s(X;G) \cong H_k^s(X,a;G), \; k \geqslant 2.
$$
But when I look for $k=1$ I obtain (since $H_0(a;G) \cong G$) a short sequence
$$ 
   0 \to H_1^s(X;G) \xrightarrow{i} H_1^s(X,a;G) \xrightarrow{j} G \to H_0^s(X;G).
$$
As before $i$ is injective. But there is a problem with surjectivity. Is there a way to proove that $H_1^s(X;G) \cong H_1^s(X,a;G)$ using this sequence (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the map $k: G \to H^s_0(X; G)$ is injective, so $\operatorname{im} j = \ker k = 0$.  Then, $\operatorname{im} i = \ker j = H^s_1(X, a; G)$, demonstrating surjectivity of $i$ and the isomorphism.

Why is $k$ injective?  It is the map on $0$-th homology groups induced by the inclusion of the point $\{a\} \hookrightarrow X$.  Consider two $0$-chains in $\{a\}$,
$$
\sigma, \tau: \Delta^0 \to \{a\}
$$
and the compositions
$$
\Delta^0 \to \{a\} \overset{\iota}{\to} X.
$$

Because the space $\{a\}$ is a point, $\sigma = \tau$ *at the chain level*, so $\iota\sigma = \iota\tau$ is a generator in $H^s_0(X;G)$, as well.

(More generally, the inclusion of a subspace $A \hookrightarrow X$ will induce <strike>an isomorphism</strike> a monomorphism on $H^s_0$, assuming that $A$ is path-connected.)

Comment: Why is it injective?

Comment: I've added a bit, hopefully convincing you of that.

Comment: You said that inclusion of subspace will induce an isomorphism on $H_0^s$ if $A$ is path connected. What about $A = \{0\}$ and $X = \{0,1\}$ with discrete topology? I think it isn't true. Monomorphism maybe you mean?

Comment: You can generalize this even more: the inclusion $A\hookrightarrow X$ induces an injection $H_0(A)\hookrightarrow H_0(X)$ iff each path-component of $X$ contains at most one path-component of $A$.

Comment: @StefanH. cool! do you have a reference to this result? it is interesting  to see a proof

Comment: Yes, of course.  I was thinking "an isomorphism with its image."  I'll fix that.

Comment: @Nimza  I don't know if the proof can be found in literature, but it is an exercise in Hatcher's book, where you can also find a proof (p. 109) that a 0-chain, i.e. a sum of points, is a boundary iff the sum of the coefficients is zero for each individual path-component. With this fact the proof for the injectivity isn't difficult. Another exercise with a similar proof is to show that the homomorphism is surjective iff $A$ meets each path-component of $X$.